# Pass data to jquery after php form submitted

Tags: php, jquery, facebook

I have a php code which upload file to the server then I have a facebook publish api.
What I want to do is after the user input completely inserted to db via php then pass the user posted data to 
jquery facebook api then FB api will automatically get the data and publish to user feed.

What I have done

- PHP upload file to server and data store in db (Plain php), Not ajax
  because I have no idea how to upoad file via ajax
- FB:api post to user feed with hard-code data

Not Done yet

Pass inserted data to jquery, and automatically trigger the FB post api
(I need help here)

Comment: Off topic: File upload isn't possible using AJAX. Most sites that mimic the experience submit their files to a hidden iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always echo out the values you need:

```
<?php
    $phpValue = "This is the value.";
?>

<script>
    var phpValue = <?=$phpValue;?>;
    console.log(phpValue);
</script>
```

Here's a snippet from an official [Facebook SDK example](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/with_js_sdk.php) where this is done:

```
[...]
<script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId: '<?php echo $facebook->getAppID() ?>',
          cookie: true,
          xfbml: true,
          oauth: true
        });
[...]
```

Comment: <?php echo $tagName;?> 
I got this output in my Google chrome console. 
var phpValue = "<?php echo $phpValue;?>"; //I added double quotes here otherwise js return error.

Comment: Your file needs to be a `.php` file, otherwise the code won't parse.

Comment: Omg, any other way to parse the php code in js?   because i prefer js always .js